# download packages for different distribution with apt

Tags: linux, debian, apt, dependencies

I want to download a `.deb` package with it's dependencies for a different distribution.

I have many Linux systems in my company: Ubuntu 11.04, 11.10, 12.10, and Debian 5 and 6.

The command to download a full dependency tree would be `apt-get -d install package`.

I'm currently using a Debian 6 (squeeze), and downloading packages for the same distribution works fine. I tried downloading (*without* installing) packages tree by changing my `sources.list` into Debian 5 (lenny) sources.

However I get the following error:

```
# apt-get -d install python-lxml
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-lxml : Depends: python (< 2.6) but 2.6.6-3+squeeze7 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Running a different OS for each distro will result in 12+ machines. I'm looking for a clearer solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't mix distros/releases. It's asking for an unmaintainable broken mess.

Comment: However if I'm using the mechanism only for downloading and not installing, there should be no problem.

Comment: The fact that you say that with a straight face illustrates just how little you understand the purpose of a package manager.

Comment: It sounds very much like you're looking for the wrong solution to the problem.

Comment: @Shadur Yep, I know that APT is a package manager. Nevertheless I want to use it as a download manager in this specific situation. Unless there's a tool which downloads dependency trees. I know none, and it seems that APT can do it fairly well with the right configuration. So be it.

Comment: @iTayb, you risk muddling up the dependencies (extant or available) of your host system with the dependencies of the downloadee. Make *sure* you know what you are doing, and set up the machinery for the guest. But if you do it right, and you ask for `xemacs` and its dependencies, it should include the whole stack right down to the kernel, so I doubt this is what you have in mind.

Comment: @vonbrand Once the system will be stable, there will be no future problems. And the machine is virtual, so going back if I fail is a piece of cake.
And the whole dependency tree is exactly what i have in mind. Perhaps I'll skip the most basic packages that comes with the distribution, and if it fails, download the whole full dependency tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

APT's core job is to resolve dependencies. So you can't really blame it for complaining about dependencies.

You'll need to invoke it with a different configuration so that it doesn't mix the package databases. Keep separate `apt.conf` and `sources.list` files and  for each distribution, e.g..

```
apt-get -o Dir::Etc::Main=/path/to/precise/apt.conf -d …
```

with `apt.conf` containing at least

```
Dig::State::status "/path/to/precise/status";
APT::Get::Download-Only "true";
```

You may need to symlink or replicate some files in `/etc/apt` in the `/path/to/precise` directory (depending on what you have in them).

**Do not run apt-get as root when you pass an alternate database**. If `apt-get` has permission to modify your system and you accidentally misconfigure something or turn off `-d`, you could seriously mess up your system. Run `apt-get` with only the privileges it needs, which as long as you're only downloading stuff doesn't include root. You will need to have enough permissions to write to the cache directory `/var/cache/apt` and its contents; I recommend creating a group for that (`addgroup aptcache; chgrp -R aptcache /var/cache/apt; chmod -R g+w /var/cache/apt` and adding yourself to it).

Comment: That would *probably* work, but the first time he makes a single mistake -- and he will -- it's going to leave his system an unrecoverable mess.

Comment: @Shadur How so? The databases are kept separate. Oh, yes, I forgot to mention something important: don't run that as root, so you can't mess up.

Comment: They're only separate as long as he never *ever* forgets *any* of the steps whenever he swaps between trees.

Comment: @Shadur What steps? What swap? Each call to `apt-get` is independent. Either it's running as root with no alternate `apt.conf`, or it's not running as root and so can't install anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to discern what you intend to do with these packages after downloading them, which would really help.

If you are downloading these packages for future installation in another machine, and you want to keep them around locally, I would recommend creating a partial apt repository for each distro using [reprepro](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/286).  If you have a lot of debian/ubuntu systems in your company, you will probably want to do this anyway.

In my environment I have a python xmlrpc server on the repository and the clients send the output of `dpkg --get-selections` to be merged with the partial package list on the repository, helping to keep the local repository in sync.  They are very simple scripts, and when I get the time I'll post them to github.

If you are needing to use these packages on a local machine after the download, and the packages aren't built for the system you are using, you may want to investigate using [schroot](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/schroot_-_chroot_for_any_users).  The `schroot` package will allow you to run a `chroot` of each distribution so that you can test your code, or whatever else you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I really, REALLY can't recommend enough that you decide on a single distribution and enforce its use on the network unless you particularly like spending five times as much time and effort making sure all systems are up to date and security issues patched.

At the very least, debian Lenny was declared end-of-life [almost a year ago](http://www.debian.org/News/2012/20120310) -- there won't *be* any more security updates. I should not have to tell you how bad an idea it is to keep running it.

I'm a little less familiar with ubuntu's life cycle, but I'm willing to bet the 04/11 variant isn't being kept up to date anymore either.

Furthermore, even if you manage to get apt to do what you're asking, you're intentionally disabling so many internal safeguards that a single mistake will leave your system a horrifying mess

If you really absolutely HAVE to have all those distributions running, perhaps you'd be better off telling each apt to use a caching http proxy like [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) that you set up on a central server in order to minimize bandwidth use and exposure to the outside.

Comment: The linux machines are testing models for my company's apps. We wish for maximum compatibility in different configurations and distributions, and that's why we need to setup somehow old end-of-life releases.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a docker image for the distro that you want to download packages for  and grab them from there. SO answer for getting dependencies [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41428445/943773).

```
# Get the distro image of choice
docker pull debian:stretch-slim

# Run the image binding the current (host) directory to container
docker run -it --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/packages debian:stretch-slim bash
```

At your docker prompt

```
# Change to the packages directory
cd packages

# Update your packages list
apt update

# Define what packages (and their dependencies) you want to download
PACKAGES="wget unzip"

# Downloads to `/packages` i.e. your PWS on host
apt-get download $(apt-cache depends --recurse --no-recommends --no-suggests \
  --no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances \
  --no-pre-depends ${PACKAGES} | grep "^\w")
exit
```